Installing open-watcom on debian 12
Im trying install open-watcom 1.9 or fork 2.0 via
chmod +x open-watcom-2_0-c-linux-x64
sudo ./open-watcom-2_0-c-linux-x64
malloc(): corrupted top size

chmod +x open-watcom-c-linux-1.9
sudo ./open-watcom-c-linux-1.9
Floating point exception

what i did
export TERMINFO=/lib/terminfo
export TERM=vt100

and it had no result

That ancient compiler is mostly for historical studies these days. What is your use for it?

@Someprogrammerdude just for fun

This is not a question about programming. You should ask it on a different Stack Exchange site.
